# Problema obteniendo la cantidad dentro de los hijos de un xml

Tags: python, xml

buenas tardes tengo el siguiente codigo para leer un archivo xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
archivo_xml = ET.parse('files/prodinfo_ES.xml')
raiz = archivo_xml.getroot()
archivo_xml = ET.parse('files/prodinfo_ES.xml')
raiz = archivo_xml.getroot()
prueba=['AR1249','AR1253']
for p in prueba: 
  for node in raiz.iter('PRODUCT'):
   ID = node.findtext('PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER')
   if ID == p:
           caja2 = node.findtext('PACKAGING_CARTON')
           print(caja2)
```

mi objetivo es obtener los valores de PACKAGING_CARTON para un respectivo calculo
mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo acceder a estos valores?
el archivo xml es el siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PRODUCTINFORMATION>
<SUPPLIER>Mid Ocean Brands</SUPPLIER>
<DATE>20220209</DATE>
<TIME>03:00:03</TIME>
<LANGUAGE>ES</LANGUAGE>
<PRODUCTS>
<PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER>AR1249</PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER>
  <PRODUCT_ID>10134325</PRODUCT_ID>
  <PACKAGING_CARTON>
    <LENGTH>0,575</LENGTH>
    <WIDTH>0,275</WIDTH>
    <HEIGHT>0,215</HEIGHT>
    <SIZE_UNIT>M</SIZE_UNIT>
    <WEIGHT>13,800</WEIGHT>
    <WEIGHT_UNIT>KG</WEIGHT_UNIT>
    <VOLUME>0,034</VOLUME>
    <VOLUME_UNIT>M3</VOLUME_UNIT>
    <INNER_CARTON_QUANTITY>10</INNER_CARTON_QUANTITY>
    <CARTON_QUANTITY>100</CARTON_QUANTITY>
  </PACKAGING_CARTON>
</PRODUCT>
```

el resultado cuando imprimo caja  son 2 líneas vacías
espero puedan ayudarme

opcion dos

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xmltodict
import json

def load_json(path: str) -> dict:  
 if path.endswith(".json"):
    print(f"> Loading JSON from '{path}'")
    with open(path, mode="r") as open_file:
        content = open_file.read()

    return json.loads(content)
elif path.endswith(".xml"):
    print(f"> Loading XML as JSON from '{path}'")
    xml = ET.tostring(ET.parse(path).getroot())
    return xmltodict.parse(xml, attr_prefix="@", cdata_key="#text", dict_constructor=dict)

print(f"> Loading failed for '{path}'")
return {}

path = "files/prodinfo_ES.xml"
data = load_json(path)
for key in data:
   print(key,':',data[key])
```

pero no se como acceder solo al valor de PACKAGING_CARTON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo utilizo [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/). Te permite usar el contenido del xml como si fuera un diccionario.

```
import xmltodict
my_base_number = 'AR1249'
d = xmltodict.parse(the_xml)

# en tu caso    
products = d['PRODUCTINFORMATION']['PRODUCTS']['PRODUCT']

for p in products:
    if p['PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER'] == my_base_number:
        print(p['PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER'], p['PACKAGING_CARTON']['CARTON_QUANTITY'])
```

Comment: no tuve oportunidad de probarlo, pero esa es la idea del funcionamiento

Comment: no logro hacer que funcione tu respuesta te agradecería mucho si pudieras ayudarme a que funcione , saludos

Comment: que error tienes o cual es el problema al intentar lo que sugeri?

Comment: me sale el siguiente error: File "c:/Users/HP-240/Documents/CAPSA_DEV/Prices_MOB/Price.py", line 3, in <module>
    d = xmltodict.parse('files/prodinfo_ES.xml')
  File "C:\Users\HP-240\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xmltodict.py", line 327, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 5
PS C:\Users\HP-240\Documents\CAPSA_DEV\Prices_MOB>

Comment: puede que el xml este mal formado. Intenga con xml simple y ve si funciona.

Comment: mmm el problema es que el xml lo bajo de un ftp no creo que este mal formado, logre una cosa al pasarlo a un json pero no se como acceder a su información , te pongo arriba el código que use

Comment: fileptr = open("/home/aditya1117/askpython/plane.xml","r") ___ xml_content= fileptr.read() ___ dict=xmltodict.parse(xml_content) ___ tal vez estas leyendo mal el contenido del archivo

Comment: edite tu respuesta con un codigo que encontre, pero ya que se imprime como accedo a los valores y solo los del id que le pida?

Comment: No es muy relevante como lees o el origen del xml. Ya que tengas el diccionario con los datos, equivalente a `d` en mi respuesta, accedes como en mi respuesta

Comment: El diccionario es el resultado de `xmltodict.parse(the_xml)`

Comment: muchas gracias ya logre acceder y ya funciona